# Uninstall persistent driver (WinVDEdrv6.sys)

Tags: drivers, windows-11, uninstall, folder-lock

When I attempted to enable Memory Integrity in Windows 11 Pro, Windows reported that an incompatible driver, which it identified as WinVDEdrv6.sys, blocked the action (screenshot attached). The driver was not listed in Windows apps using Control Panel; in terminal mode, the command "dism /online /get-drivers /format:table" failed to list this file.

[image]

I found a post that linked the driver with NewSoftwares.net, the publisher of the file encryption app FolderLock. Months ago, I downloaded a trial version, decided I didn't need it and uninstalled the program. I did not see FolderLock, NewSoftwares or any other reference to them in Control Panel or the terminal table of drivers.

I've emailed tech support at NewSoftwares but have not received a reply to date.

I located the file WinVDEdrv6.sys in C:\Windows\SysWOW64. My questions are:
Is this a necessary driver?
How can I uninstall or safely delete it?

[pnputil /enum-drivers Output](https://pastebin.com/vDa4CVGq)

Comment: Have you tried `rapr.exe`?

Comment: What is the .inf filename associated with the driver? Edit your question instead of submitting a comment. You can determine that information by running **pnputil /enum-drivers**

Comment: Memory Integrity that I know is in Windows Defender and part of Core Isolation. If that is what you are looking at, it has not worked properly on any machine of mine no matter how new.

Comment: @John - It works perfectly fine on my machine.  The feature will tell you exactly the reason it cannot be enabled.

Comment: Same on my machine - it cannot be enabled.

Comment: I ran pnputil /enum-drivers. No helpful information. l

Comment: @David - Are you positive that not a single `.inf` is linked to WinVDEdrv6.sys? I find that improbable if it's in memory and thus preventing Core Isolation from being enabled.  Provide the entire output to something like Pastebin, and I will look at it myself. When you attempt to enable Core Isolation, it should also provide you the .inf filename associated with the driver incompatible with Core Isolation. I have fixed an system that had a driver loaded with an incompatible system, so I know exactly how to solve this problem, I just need to confirm it will work for your situation

Comment: Thanks for your help @Ramhound. I did not see a link with a .inf file. I am happy to share the output but am new to pastebin and how it would relate to stackoverflow, so my response will be delayed.

Comment: Just paste the contents into pastebin the provide a link to it, if the output contains what’s required to answer the question, I will edit the question myself and answer it.  “I did not see a link with a .inf” - There isn’t a “link”, but that command should output a .inf file that belongs to WinVDEdrv6.sys. Linked as in connected or associated to WinVDEdrv6.sys

Comment: By "link" in that context I meant "connection", not a url. Here is the pastebin link:https://pastebin.com/vDa4CVGq

Comment: Yes. Thought it would be readable with the link. I'll make it public if I need to.

Comment: It appears the driver isn’t installed but it’s existence in the folder is enough to prevent Core Isolation from being enabled, you should be able to delete it without a problem

Comment: I'll do some precautionary backup, try deleting it tomorrow and get back with the status. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I had to delete WinVDEdrv6.sys in safe mode, then enabled Memory Integrity successfully after restart.  BTW, Powertoys could not identify the process that was using the file.  Thank you for working it through with me, @Ramhound.

Comment: Suggestion: edit the comments into a singe *answer*, since this seems to have resolved the issue and might help others.

Comment: Agree. @Ramhound, it is your correct answer if you want to follow up.

Comment: @David - My suggestions didn't work. Seems like you know exactly what did work.

Answer (score 1):

WinVDEdrv6.sys was not a necessary driver on my machine. I deleted the file in safe mode, restarted, and enabled Memory Integrity with no problems. Here are the steps I took to confirm I could do this safely.

To look for any drivers associated with WinVDEdrv6.sys, I produced a list of drivers by running "pnputil /enum-drivers" in terminal mode. The list did not include references to WinVDEdrv6.sys, NewSoftwares or FolderLock. So the driver connected to WinVDEdrv6.sys was not installed, though apparently, the existence of the file was enough to block enabling Memory Integrity. Windows blocked me from deleting the file because it was shown as in use (by an unidentified process). I used safe mode to delete the file.

Based on [this post](https://www.file.net/process/winvdedrv6.sys.html), WinVDEdrv6.sys probably was created when I installed a trial version of FolderLock, and was left behind after I uninstalled the program. Many thanks to @Ramhound for his helpful comments.